# An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results in agularjs

Tags: pivot-table, pivottable.js

All works, but when I try to to show any chart from pivot I get this error

```
An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.
```

Comment: Please add the error as well, to your question.

Comment: i got  this error "An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results."